# NativeScript & Angular: how to get a reference to the template-driven form in my component?

Tags: angular, forms, nativescript

I've got a template-driven form like this:

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate>

                    <TextField
                        required
                        hint="Client Code:"
                        [class.is-invalid]="clientCodeField.invalid && clientCodeField.dirty"
                        [(ngModel)]="clientcode"
                        name="clientcode"
                        autocorrect="false"
                        returnType="done"
                        (returnPress)="onLogin()"
                        autocapitalizationType="none"
                        #clientCodeField="ngModel">
                    </TextField>

            <Button
                text="Submit"
                (tap)="onLogin()"
                class="btn-red-rounded"
                isEnabled="{{ f.valid === true }}">
            </Button>

</form>
```

I want to get a reference of the form in my conponent so I can check the validity of the form.
I tried to do it but it says that it's undefined.
How can I do this?

My attempt:

```
export class RegisterClientCodeComponent implements OnInit {

f: FormGroup;

public clientcode: string = '';

constructor() { }

public ngOnInit() {}

public onLogin() {

    if(this.f.valid) {
        return;
    }

    //do stuff
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular requires `form` tag to work with `NgForm`, we don't have one in NativeScript. So you can register `StackLayout` as `form`, probably in your app module.

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular";

registerElement("form", () => StackLayout);
```

**HTML**

```
<GridLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <form #f="ngForm" class="home-panel" backgroundColor="red">
            <TextField [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" required>
            </TextField>
            <Button text="Submit" (tap)="onSubmit()"></Button>
        </form>
    </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('f', { static: true }) form: NgForm;

onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.invalid);
}
```